How to pass a ansible vault password file while using ansible_runner in a python script
I have a very simple Python script to run an Ansible playbook (A post call to get an access token from the OAuth2 authorization server and save it in a .txt file).
I have secrets stored in ansible-vault and need to pass the vault password file when calling ansible_runner.run(). Not sure if that is possible or not but tried cmdline='--vault-password-file vault-pass.txt' and it doesnt work.
import streamlit as st 
import ansible_runner

st.header("ReadOnly view") 
st.write(f"You are logged in as {st.session_state.role} user.")
st.write(st.session_state.get('selected_site', 'No site selected'))


# Run the Ansible playbook 
gToken=ansible_runner.run(private_data_dir='/indra/ansible/playbooks',playbook='get_authtoken.yml', cmdline='--vault-password-file vault-pass.txt')

st.write(gToken.rc)
st.write(gToken.status)

OUTPUT:
ReadOnly
You are logged in as ReadOnly user.

test-nsxt01.nfv.example.net

1

failed

